# Android Get Mobile Data Signal Strength (API <17)

Tags: android

I am making an app that gets Wi-Fi and Mobile Data information.  The Wi-Fi portion of the app is working fine, but I can't seem to get the data part working.  I've heard of issues like this on Samsung phones (I'm testing on one), and I need a workaround without going above my API level of 15.

Here is my current code:

```
class myPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {

        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {

            mobileStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
            mobileStrength = (2 * mobileStrength) - 113;

        } else {

            mobileStrength = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();

        }
    }
}
```

But it returns `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
 * Gets the signal level from a <tt>SignalStrength</tt> as a value in the
 * range 0-4.  This info is hidden from the public API, so this method
 * obtains it via reflection.
 *
 * @return the signal level, or 0 if Google has broken the hack
 */
public static int getSignalLevel(final SignalStrength signal) {
    try {
        final Method m = SignalStrength.class.getDeclaredMethod("getLevel", (Class[]) null);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (Integer) m.invoke(signal, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.debug(TAG, "Google hates developers", e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns 4 (I'm assuming that's the best).  Is there a way to get it from 0-100?  If not, should I just use `[result] * 20` of `[result] * 25`?

Comment: @AngryCupcake274 If you want to see how that method comes up with a value, look it up in the AOSP and adapt it to your purposes.  Personally, I feel that there's a degree of "bar inflation" in the default implementation.

Comment: Do you know a way to get the mobile data speed like `WifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()`?  I don't care about what kind of network it is, I just need a number.  (I have to ask here because I can't post for 90 minutes)

Comment: Also, how can you get the signal strength on-demand?  I would like to not have to wait until the signal strength changed.

Comment: @AngryCupcake274 I don't know of any way to get it on demand before API 17.  I register a listener when my app starts and hope it changes before I need it.  I've never tried to determine the mobile data speed.

Comment: Turns out if I register the listener twice, it seems to give me an output.  I'll have to look into this more.  For data speed, I downloaded a file from my website and checked how long it took.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have set the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file ?

If not, set this to read the phone state.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

Yours sincerely,

Flemming

Comment: Still returns `null`.